# Hiddenfield loses value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a form and a GridView on the same page. When the user saves the form, it creates an ID. I need to set the id to a HiddenField. I then need that HiddenField for the GridView. But as soon as the code finishes the save method of the form, the HiddenField gets reset to 0.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>        
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveMaintenance" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSaveMaintenance" OnClientClick="return ValidateSaveWithoutPieces()" OnClick="btnSaveMaintenance_Click" runat="server" style="float:left" CssClass="btnSaveSmall" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
```

I put the save button in an update panel to stop the page from refreshing and closing (Normally once the save button is clicked it will close the form but I needed it to stay open).

At the top of the page I put the HiddenField:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewID" runat="server" />
```

Then in the `btnSaveMaintenance_Click` method I set the value of the HiddenField

```
protected void btnSaveMaintenance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int tmpParentID = tmpID;
        if (ParentID.HasValue)
            tmpParentID = ParentID.Value;

        Maintenance newMain = new Maintenance
        {
            ID = tmpID,
            Company_ID = Company.Current.CompanyID,
            VehicleTrailer = tmpType,
            LinkedID = (long)tmpParentID,
            DBRowStatus = JobPiece.RowStatus.ToCreate
        };

        main.Add(newMain);;
        hfNewID.Value = tmpID.ToString(); //set value to hiddenfield

        if (ParentID.HasValue)
        {
            Save(Reg, ParentID.Value);
            List<Maintenance> Newmain = Maintenance.GetMainteneceItemsByParentID(Company.Current.CompanyID,
                 ParentID.Value,
                 PageType,
                 "Active");
            ViewState["Maintenance"] = Newmain;
            gvMaintenance.DataSource = Newmain;
            gvMaintenance.DataBind();
            udpMain.Update();
        }
}
```

But when I try call the HiddenField in another function is keeping returning blank. How do I get the HiddenField to keep the value?

Comment: loosing while postback??

Comment: Probably you have to put your hidden field inside your updatePanel, under  contentTemplate, and not on top of page.

Comment: Please Put Hidden Field in the Update Panel.I hope this will help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:
Put your hidden field inside your updatePanel, under contentTemplate, and not on top of page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate> 
             // you have to put your hidden in this place
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewID" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveMaintenance" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```